# Xamarin.UWP CarouselPage OnAppearing() bug

Tags: xamarin, uwp

App.xaml.cs

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Home());
```

Home.xaml.cs

```
    public Home()
    {
        Children.Insert(0,new CarPage1());
        Children.Insert(1,new CarPage2());
        Children.Insert(2,new CarPage3());
        CurrentPage = Children[1];
    }
```

CarPage1.xaml.cs

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        DisplayAlert("Page1", null, "ok");
    }
```

CarPage2.xaml.cs

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        DisplayAlert("Page2", null, "ok");
    }
```

CarPage3.xaml.cs

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        DisplayAlert("Page3", null, "ok");
    }
```

Run UWP Page2 alert show.
[image]

click ok why Page1 alert show?
[image]

click UWP left symbol why no Page1 alert show?
[image]

Run Xamarin.Android work fine!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is just the case as you said.

And I have created a new issue about this problem. You can follow it up here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15577 .

Thanks for your support and feedback for xamarin.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Write and Post to GitHub is a tire work , Thanks a lot a lot a lot.